# How do I convert this to using Linq to dataset?

Tags: c#, linq

How do I convert this to using Linq to dataset?

```
foreach (Row row in Rows) 
{ 
    if (row.material> 0) 
        sumtid += row.time * row.material; 
    else 
        sumtid += row.time; 
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var sumtid = Rows.Sum(x => x.time * (x.materials > 0 ? x.materials : 1));
```

or

```
var sumtid = Rows.Sum(x => x.materials > 0 ? x.time * row.materials : x.time);
```

I've assumed your `Rows` variable is `IEnumerable<Row>`.

***Edit***

Another way of solving the problem:

```
var sumtid = Rows.Select(x => x.materials > 0 ? x.time * row.materials : x.time)
                 .Sum();
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @MarcinJuraszek's answer, you can also use your code as is:

```
var sumtid = Rows.Sum(row =>
    {
        if (row.material> 0) 
            return row.time * row.material; 
        else 
            return row.time; 
    });
```